# Text Preprocessing for NLP but from List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text, nlp

I'm attempting to do an NLP project with a goodreads data set. my data set is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary looks like so (the list is called 'reviews'):

```
>>> reviews[0]
{'user_id': '8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d60773d4d',
'book_id': '23310161',
'review_id': 'f4b4b050f4be00e9283c92a814af2670',
'rating': 4,
'review_text': 'Fun sequel to the original.',
'date_added': 'Tue Nov 17 11:37:35 -0800 2015',
'date_updated': 'Tue Nov 17 11:38:05 -0800 2015',
'read_at': '',
'started_at': '',
'n_votes': 7,
'n_comments': 0}
```

There are 700k+ of these dictionaries in my dataset.

**First question**: I am only interested in the elements `'rating'` and `'review_text'`. I know I can delete elements from each dictionary, but how do I do it for all of the dictionaries?

**Second question**: I am able to do sentence and word tokenization of an individual dictionary in the list by specifying the dictionary in the list, then the element `'review_text'` within the dictionary like so:

```
paragraph = reviews[0]['review_text']
```

And then applying `sent_tokenize` and `word_tokenize` like so:

```
print(sent_tokenize(paragraph))
print(word_tokenize(paragraph))
```

But how do I apply these methods to the entire data set? I am stuck here, and cannot even attempt to do any of the text preprocessing (lower casing, removing punctuation, lemmatizing, etc).

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the **first question**, you can simply put them into `dataframe` with only your interesting columns (i.e. `rating` and `review_text`). This is to avoid looping and managing them record by record and is also easy to be manipulated on the further processes.

After you came up with the `dataframe`, use `apply` to preprocess (e.g. *lower*, *tokenize*, *remove punctuation*, *lemmatize*, and *stem*) your text column and generate new column named `tokens` that store the preprocessed text (i.e. `tokens`). This is to satisfy the **second question**.

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import string

punc_list = list(string.punctuation)
porter = PorterStemmer()    
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def text_processing(row):
    all_words = list()
    # sentence tokenize
    for sent in sent_tokenize(row['review_text']):
        # lower words and tokenize
        words = word_tokenize(sent.lower())
        # lemmatize
        words_lem = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in words]
        # remove punctuation
        used_words = [w for w in words_lem if w not in punc_list]
        # stem
        words_stem = [porter.stem(w) for w in used_words]
        all_words += words_stem
    return all_words

# create dataframe from list of dicts (select only interesting columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(reviews, columns=['user_id', 'rating', 'review_text'])

df['tokens'] = df.apply(lambda x: text_processing(x), axis=1)
print(df.head())
```

example of output:

> ```
>   user_id  rating              review_text                        tokens
> 0       1       4        Fun sequel to the        [fun, sequel, to, the]
> 1       2       2  It was a slippery slope  [it, wa, a, slipperi, slope]
> 2       3       3     The trick to getting         [the, trick, to, get]
> 3       4       3           The bird had a           [the, bird, had, a]
> 4       5       5      That dog likes cats        [that, dog, like, cat]
> ```

Finally, if you don’t prefer `dataframe`, you can export it as other formats such as csv (`to_csv`), json (`to_json`), and list of dicts (`to_dict('records')`).

Hope this would help

Comment: thank you! that was perfect. When I was trying, I was not calling the row in the df in the for loop properly. this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your help!